# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set

Tags: java

Не загружается не может найти локал сет, есть два файла локали en и ру, никак не хотят подключаться.

Класс Main

```
public class Main extends Application {

private static Locale DEFAULT_LOCALE = new Locale("en");

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Locale.setDefault(DEFAULT_LOCALE);

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();

   // fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../fxml/todolist.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("todolist.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("TestBundle", new Locale("ru")));

    Parent fxmlMain = fxmlLoader.load();
    MainController mainController = fxmlLoader.getController();
    mainController.setMainStage(stage);

    stage.setTitle(fxmlLoader.getResources().getString("todo_list"));
    stage.setMinHeight(650);
    stage.setMinWidth(750);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(fxmlMain, 650, 675));
    stage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Иерархия программы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
|

Пробовал варианты, перемещал в папку ресурс и где вообще весь проект:

```
fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("TestBundle", new Locale("ru"))); // или
    fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("ru.todolist.javafx.bundles.TestBundle_en")); // или
    fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("ru/todolist/javafx/bundles/TestBundle", new Locale("ru"))); // или
```

Ошибка

```
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at** javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2541)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at ru.todolist.javafx.start.Main.start(Main.java:30)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application ru.todolist.javafx.start.Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Была проблема не в локалях! А пути к файлам fxml!
Вопрос решен переносом пакета fxml с файлами в папку resources.
maven clean -> package -> и в папке target появляются папка fxml с файлами, ее небыло при создание папки сборки.
также в Main классе в методе start прописываю: fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxml/todolist.fxml"));